# Add Required to Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following Angular directive:

```
app.directive('basicInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'DirectiveTemplates/BasicInput.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            visual: '@',
            placeholder: '@',
            pattern: '=',
            ngChange: '='            
        }
    };
});
```

With the following Template:

```
<ng-form name="basicInput">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input">{{visual}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" required ng-pattern="pattern">
        <div ng-messages="basicInput.input.$error" class="help-block">
            <span ng-message="required"> Required</span>
            <span ng-message="pattern"> Invalid Characters or is too short</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Which I call in html as (for example):

```
<basic-input ng-model="formData.official_name" data-visual="Official Name" data-placeholder="Name" pattern="regex.short"></basic-input>
```

My Question is, how can I make the 'required' on the input tag from the template optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Directive:

```
scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        visual: '@',
        placeholder: '@',
        pattern: '=',
        ngChange: '=',
        isRequired: '='
    }
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="isRequired" name="input" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-pattern="pattern">
```

Usage:

```
<basic-input ng-model="formData.official_name" is-required="false" data-visual="Official Name" data-placeholder="Name" pattern="regex.short"></basic-input>
```

Comment: I had to change isRequired to @ instead of = to make it work so that it wasn't looking into $scope for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

ngRequired 
you can set ng-required attribute to true or false ,, according to an attribute

docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: I've tried setting ng-required="true" without success.

Comment: have you tried to pass a variable to it ?? instead of literal false or true ?

Comment: Yes, I tried passing a variable to it, the problem is, it sets ng-required on the ng-form tag, not on the input tag where I would like it.

Comment: can you show me your code ???
NOTE : I mean to use ng-required with the input in your template ,, not on your directive !